# I open "Word" but the screen remains blank

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

When I open Microsoft Word 365 on my Windows 10 laptop, I see that it opens (I see the icon in the taskbar), but the screen remains blank - I do not see Word anywhere - I see only the desktop.
What happened?

Comment: Is this the first run of Word?

Comment: @harrymc no, it worked fine just this morning.

Comment: Try in menu *File > Options > Advanced*, Display section to check "Disable hardware graphics acceleration", click OK and close all Office applications before starting Word.

Comment: Do you mean the Word menu? I do not see it - all I see from Word is the icon in the toolbar. When I click the icon in the toolbar, nothing happens - the window does not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to update your Office 365 to the latest version. [Repair your Office from Control Panel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) to fix it.

You can try to open Word in Safe Mode to check if it can work properly. Here is a Microsoft official support article for your reference: [I get a "stopped working" error when I start Office applications on my PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-get-a-stopped-working-error-when-i-start-office-applications-on-my-pc-52bd7985-4e99-4a35-84c8-2d9b8301a2fa). You can follow the guide of the article to troubleshooting the issue.

You can close all unnecessary programs temporarily including 3rd-party Anti-virus software, to check if these application are causing Word's issue.

In addition, you can try to log in your computer with other user accounts to do some check. Will Word start smoothly under a different profile?

You can also troubleshoot the display issue according to [Display issues in Office client applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/settings/office-display-issues).

Comment: Reparing Office as you suggested solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 needs an Internet connection. Not constant, but upon launching one of its components, be it Word, Excel, etc... to check on license validity and updates.

Is your Internet connection OK?

Comment: Yes, since I wrote this post..

Comment: You could have written it from any other device but the one with your Word problem on it, but I'm glad to see your issue is now a thing of the past.